# Java regular expresion group closing

Tags: java, regex

I get the unclosed group error from the compiler for the following regular expression :

```
Pattern.compile("((([-+])|^)?(\\d*))?(([x])(([\\^])([1-9][0-9]*))?)?");
```

Can someone tell me what the error might be?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://regex101.com/r/OuCBWo/2. Are you sure this is the line causing the error?

Comment: whats the goal of this expression?

Comment: Checked in Java, cannot reproduce

Comment: Yes, this is the one. I know that on regex101 is not a problem, but in Intellij it appears to be: https://imgur.com/ZWdqbwM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((([-+])|^)?(\\d*))?(([x])(([\\^])([1-9][0-9]*))?)?
123    3  2 2    21 12   223     33           32 1
```

So it is absolutely fine. The error lies elsewhere, wrong constant name, or whatever.

Error: `([\\^])` should have been `(\\^)`

Comment: The problem that I saw might causing it lies in this type of expression: ([\\^]), creating a group that signals the appearance of ^ char.

Comment: So what if you changed `([\\^])` to `(\\^)` or even `\\^`?

Comment: Yes, it worked with (\\^). I don't have any idea why it has this error with ([\\^]).